# "Can't bind to 'ngFor' or ngIf since it isn't a known property of '<element>' error with CommonModule imported. Angular 11/12 with lazyloading

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, lazy-loading

This question was asked many times (without the lazy loading part) and the common answer is to make sure you have included CommonModule in the offending module.ts file (providing it not a syntax problem). Many of these questions go unanswered..... I am one such person who couldn't find an answer to this problem until now....so I am posing the question for the umpteen time hoping to solicit a none of the answers that went before and for the benefits for those who come after.

say this is your offending module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { RidePageRoutingModule } from './ride-routing.module';

import { RidePage } from './ride.page';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RidePageRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [RidePage]
```

and this is the offending code:

```
 <div *ngIf="vehicles">
    <li *ngFor="let v of vehicles"s>v.name</li>
  </div>
```

and this is your app-routing-module:

```
...
....
 {
    path: 'ride',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/ride/ride.module').then( m => m.RidePageModule)
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

The NG0303 error will show up

Answer (score 4):

When I do lazy loading, I put `CommonModule` into a shared module and ensure each feature (lazy loaded) module pulls in the shared module. I have an example here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-Routing/tree/master/APM-Final

**Shared Module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { StarComponent } from './star.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    StarComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    StarComponent,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

**Feature Module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { ProductListComponent } from './product-list.component';
import { ProductDetailComponent } from './product-detail.component';
import { ProductEditComponent } from './product-edit/product-edit.component';

import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([...])
  ],
  declarations: [
    ProductListComponent,
    ProductDetailComponent,
    ProductEditComponent,
  ]
})
export class ProductModule { }
```

[image]

Comment: Elegant..I like it...but its not the answer I am looking for....I will give it credit though.

Comment: Any way you can create a Stackblitz that demonstrates the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The specific problem in this scenario lies in the app-routing-module.

```
...
....
 {
    path: 'ride',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/ride/ride.module').then( m => m.RidePageModule)
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

apparently because the way lazy loading works you have to include the option **preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules**
like so:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{ preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
```

I hope this save somebody some time.

Comment: I don’t think this is the actual solution to your problem. It might (accidentally) fix it for you.. but this option basically kills lazy loading..

Comment: I agree that this most likely isn't really resolving the problem.

Comment: @mikeOne I thought so myself because it basically says load all the modules....which would make u believe it's not lazy loading....but without this the directives ngIf...ngFor...don't work. I would love if someone could provide another answer. Its not a CommonModule problem I can assure you of that.

Comment: I have seriously NEVER ever had to use that preloadingStrategy to make this work. And I work with loads of complicated module setups (with lazy loading modules as well). The problem must be somewhere else. The most likely culprit is not actually importing your shared or feature module itself at the higher level. I’ve made that error myself before..

Comment: @MikeOne ...could you expand on suggestion with an example....thanks

Comment: That’s a bit hard without seeing your entire app…

Comment: @MikeOne I meant show me an example of the mistake you have made.